# How can I lock a resizable div to the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I have 2 resizable divs in a container. One resizable div is contained in the second one.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1" class="droppable resizable1">
    <div id="div2" class="droppable resizable2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actually, I have two problems with these divs and I think they are linked.

First, if I resize `div1`, `div2` and again `div1` to the bottom, `div2` is moving out of the container.

The second problems happens in the same way. The `div2` is going up with the same tests as in the first problem, that's why I think they are linked.

I have tried to change my CSS but I haven't found a solution. At start I thought it comes from the minHeight of JQueryUI so I checked the documentation but my resizable function looks right.

I have made a https://jsfiddle.net/Spydaxx/4ez2xtan/85/ so you can see what I am trying to do.

I want the two divs to be lock at the bottom and resizable upwards. Actually, I have some troubles with the position when resizing but the resize itself looks well.

Thank you for your help and your time.

Comment: are you trying to be able to resize both freely/individually as high or low as you want inside of the container?

Comment: Yes, I need to resize them individually. I have set `minHeight` limits beacause they should always be visible by the user.

Comment: Don't nest the two divs and that fixes the problem.

Comment: I need them to be nested because they are droppable in my application. I use `greedy: true` from droppable to reach the second one.

Answer (score 0):

so if I understand correctly you want to be able to move either div freely within the height restrictions you set. unless you need the divs nested, which I'm not sure if that would work with what you're trying to do, this will work

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1" class="droppable resizable1"></div>
  <div id="div2" class="droppable resizable2"></div>
</div>

$(".resizable1").resizable({
    handles: 'n',
    containment:'#container',
  minHeight: 100
});
$(".resizable2").resizable({
    handles: 'n',
  containment: '#container',
  minHeight: 50
})
```

I didn't change any css so I didn't include the code here. just don't nest the divs and change the container for div2

Comment: The problem is that I need the divs to be nested. As they are droppable in my application, if I drop in the red one, it will also drop in the blue one if they arenot nested. I solved this issue with the `greedy: true` option on resizable and a nest of the two divs :/

Comment: are you using jquery draggabable/droppable?

Comment: I'm using JQueryUI

Comment: when you say `drop in` do you mean like actually drag something and drop it into the red or like drag the red itself into the blue?

Comment: I mean drag another element and drop it into the red or into the blue. Blue and red are zones where I drop other elements.